# OpenCV video capture fails in Anaconda

Tags: python, linux, opencv, video, anaconda

The following fails on Anaconda 1.9 on Linux only:

```
import cv2
import sys
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(sys.argv[1])

ret, frame = cap.read()
if not ret:
    print "capture failed"
```

Tested with Anaconda-1.9.2-Linux-x86_64 on Ubuntu 12.04LTS, Debian Wheezy.  The same code using the same input file works in Anaconda on Windows 7, and also using the python-opencv 2.3.1-7 package on Ubuntu.  The input file is H.264 video in MP4 container.  Anaconda is installed system-wide under /opt/anaconda, and /opt/anaconda/bin is in the path.

Incidentally, I do not have an example of Anaconda's `cv2.VideoCapture` working on *any* input file on Linux.  After I discovered this, I tested a few other files, same result.  Writing files also fails.

Is there a trick to getting Anaconda cv2 fully working on Linux?

**UPDATE** This is still not working in recent versions of Anaconda, for example Anaconda-2.2.0-Linux-x86_64 on Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

Comment: You missed the part where you post the error message ;).

Comment: @Veedrac: the error is that ret is false, there is no exception or error code or anything like that.

Comment: Ah, well that makes things hard. Good luck.

Comment: I tested your code on my archlinux, on mp4 movie, and it's working. Maybe that can be helpfull -> http://www.codedisqus.com/7QQzWPgggX/reading-a-h264-rtsp-stream-into-python-and-opencv.html

Answer (score 0):

**Install OpenCV from this Conda forge:**
`conda install -c loopbio ffmpeg-feature gtk2-feature opencv`